# MacBook Air M1 - What is this spare part of the display called?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware, apple-silicon, macos

I broke my display by closing it while something was left in the gap between body and display panel. There seems to be some sort of sticker covering the lower part of the display and **I wonder if this is available as a spare part for purchase?**

[image: MacBook Air M1 Broken Part]

Comment: Not easy to tell from the photo, but these bits don't look good either - https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU9i6.jpg What do they look like against a less-busy image?

Comment: Thank you @Tetsujin This part is ok. It's the lower part only. I'm mean... "only".

Comment: Hmm… OK. Are those bits in the image itself?

Comment: The display is not too clean. After cleaning it, all looks fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part is called a *bezel*.

You could try authorized repair shops or the secondary market (eBay) for a part like this but since these MacBooks are so new, it’s unlikely to be a very common part.

It also appears to be adhered to the glass assembly so you may have to replace the entire display to effect that repair.